# Diff two branches in git ignoring one part of one of those branches

Tags: git, git-diff

Say I have:

```
          e - d <- branch1
         /
a - b - c <- master
     \
       e' - d' <- branch2
```

How can I diff branch1 and branch2 ignoring changes in master branch (commit c above) - so effectively the result of rebasing branch2 on master and then diffing (assuming there are no conflicts) ?

Comment: (I feel like I've answered this one before...) The short answer is "you can't, but you *can* make a rebased copy of the branch or branches and then diff their new tip commits" and that gets you what you want. You can use the "detached HEAD" mode of Git to make these rebased copies; as soon as you `git checkout branch1` or whatever, the extra commit copies are abandoned, to be garbage-collected in about a month.

Comment: Thanks @torek - I feel I asked this before :P. Still there should be a way without rebasing, maybe some script or something

Comment: You could also make a commit that backs out the unwanted commit(s), on a detached HEAD. I think rebasing the wanted commits is more likely to work well in general though. Writing a script that just cherry-picks the desired commit(s) to a detached HEAD, then runs `git diff`, would be easy: see the actual `git rev-list` run inside the existing rebase code that selects the commits to be copied.

Comment: See rebase may end up producing conflicts etc, plus it's usually not that fast, plus it's an extra step. If there is a fundamental design reason why this is necessary (which may very well be the case) I 'd be curious to hear about it

Comment: The fundamental design issue is that each commit has only a snapshot of a tree. You want to derive a snapshot that doesn't exist, and the only way to do that is to rather literally build it, either by revert (which can produce merge conflicts) or cherry-pick (which can produce merge conflicts).